# XML: Enforce child structure for two elements through XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Is it possible (and if so, how) to enforce with XML Schema that two elements in a document *must* contain an identical substructure? For instance, I'd like to express that any foo has two children, bar1 and bar2, and bar1 has to have the same child structure as bar2:

```
<foo>
  <bar1>
    <baz>hello, world</baz>
  </bar1>
  <bar2>
    <baz>hello, world</baz>
  </bar2>
</foo>
```

Is *key* and *keyref* the right way to go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure - define a named `<xs:complexType>` which represents the "contents" of the bar1 and bar2 nodes, and use that to define the two elements:

```
<xs:schema id="foo" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="bar1" type="subbar" />
      <xs:element name="bar2" type="subbar" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="subbar">
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="baz" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but apparently I wasn't clear enough with my question. The problem is that I want to make sure that the child content is *exactly* the same for bar1,2 - e.g., if bar1/baz has the string content "hello, world" then bar2/baz must also have "hello, world" as content.